# Mongodb updated password is not saved into the database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am working on a functionality that allows users to update their password. However, the hashed password is not updated into the mongodb database for some reasons.

This is my front end code for updateProfile:

```
    updateProfile() {
        const modified_auth={
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            nid: this.state.nid,
            password: this.state.password,
        }

        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/userprofile/update', modified_auth)
            .then(res =>{
                console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => {console.log('Err' + err);});
    }
```

This is my back end route to update the user profile:

```
router.route('/update').post((req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    Auth.findOne({
        $or: [
            { email: req.body.email },
            { nid: req.body.nid }
        ]
    })
    .then(auth => {
        auth.name = req.body.name;
        auth.nid = req.body.nid
        auth.email = req.body.email;
        console.log(auth.password);
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                auth.password = hash;
                console.log(auth.password);
            });
        });
        console.log(auth.password);
        auth.save()
            .then(() => res.json('Auth updated!'))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
    console.log(auth.password);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

I put in a few print statements. Those are what I got back:

```
$2a$10$uKeVPatEK3QqpvtdjvQYaeELnrAfuOlOhbG/4lJBV8brqLzcU5enW
$2a$10$uKeVPatEK3QqpvtdjvQYaeELnrAfuOlOhbG/4lJBV8brqLzcU5enW
$2a$10$uKeVPatEK3QqpvtdjvQYaeELnrAfuOlOhbG/4lJBV8brqLzcU5enW
$2a$10$K8eKneNAxYC2Xrym3eSXM.xas0ZrmIDVUe8WnmmghgvmzT.uw5l/e
```

I could not figure out why the new password was not saved into the database.

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Are you using Mongoose by any chance or just the MongoDB node.js driver?

Comment: @cischa Yes. I am using Mongoose.

Comment: By any chance, was there another document inserted into the database with the updated key-values?

Comment: @cischa, Yes, when I updated nid ... it changed into the db

Comment: So there was both the old AND the new, updated document in the database?

Comment: @cischa, however, I wanted to the users to have the control to update their passwords.

Comment: Right. Do you mind checking if _id is present in the auth object before you call save()? i,e. What is the value of auth._id?

Comment: @cischa, the auth._id is 5de5e2bafeb2bfb692594750 before save(). If I modify other things besides the password, seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the password generation happens **asynchronously** alongside the Document save() call. Since the intended behavior is to include the new password in the document update, you can place the save() call inside of the callback for the password generation to ensure that the new document has the updated password:

```
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                auth.password = hash;
                console.log(auth.password);
                auth.save()
                    .then(() => res.json('Auth updated!'))
                    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
            })
        })
```

Comment: Could you mind explain a bit more on how to make password generation synchronous?

Comment: Sorry, yes I made an edit! Does that help @SkipperLin ?

Comment: It worked greatly. That was really a great catch. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it.